# Is it possible to customize iptables logging to syslog?

Tags: iptables, logs, syslog

Let's say I have the following log entry from `iptables` to `syslog`:

```
Nov  3 12:04:12 mypc kernel: [  296.274134] Packet: IN=enp0s9 OUT=enp0s8 MAC=08:00:27:2f:77:23:08:00:27:86:42:0e:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.20 DST=192.168.1.11 LEN=284 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=61089 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=1335 WINDOW=32160 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

Where "`Packet:`" is my custom log-prefix defined as `iptables` rule: `... -j LOG --log-prefix "Packet: "`

The question: can `IN=enp0s9 <...> ACK PSH URGP=0` (I mean the whole string) be modified? Or it is the whole "Message" which can't be deconstructed?

In short, I want entry to look like:

```
Nov  3 12:04:12 Packet: SRC=192.168.2.20 DST=192.168.1.11 LEN=284
```

without other info. And I want to do this as custom template for syslog. Is it possible? Unfortunately it's not clear from [Syslog Documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [property replacer](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/property_replacer.html).

Put in your `rsyslog.conf` or similar a line defining a template that is the desired format of the new message, and use it in the action when you match the input line. For example,

```
$template myedit,"Packet: %msg:R,ERE,1,FIELD:Packet: .*?(SRC=.*LEN=[0-9]+).*--end%\n"
if ($msg contains "Packet: ") then {
  action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/myedit.log" template="myedit")
}
```

The template says the template variable `myedit` is the string including the `msg` property replaced by a regex (R) match, extended (ERE), group capture 1 (1), (and if no match, keep the original FIELD). The actual regex is the `Packet: .*?(SRC=.*LEN=[0-9]+).*` part. The `--end` is an obligatory part of the `%...:R,...--end%` sequence. Add a final newline, as we will replace the whole message by this template.

The following lines are the usual Rainer Script test for the lines you want to edit, and where to place the result.

Comment: Thank you very much! How is it possible to append date before everything else (see my question), should it be done with regex or using some internal syslog variable?

Comment: Upd: Nevermind, Adding `%TIMESTAMP%` Before `%msg` worked fine for me.